# Reading RAW data from an R socket

Tags: r, sockets, binary

To exchange data very fast between Python and R I programmed a rather dirty solution, which works. On linux and OSX. May it not be that I now have to get this working in windows.

The below code runs a python script that builds a raw vector which can be serialised by RApiSerialise to an R object.

```
COMMAND = "python"
PATH_TO_SCRIPT='/GetCassandraData.py'    

QueryCassandra <- function(query){
  allArgs = c(PATH_TO_SCRIPT, query)

  output.connection <- rawConnection(raw(length = 0), "r+")
  exec_wait(COMMAND, args = allArgs, std_out = output.connection)

  output <- rawConnectionValue(output.connection)
  close(output.connection)

  final <- unserializeFromRaw(output)

  return(final)
}
```

This works as intended on OSX & linux however, windows has the tendancy to put a 0x0d (Carriage return) byte before a 0x0a (line feed) byte which makes RApiSerialise unable to deserialise it.

I am now attempting to solve the problem by communicating through sockets but I do not seem to be able to find a way to read data from a make.socket() object to a raw vector.

I have tried:

```
data <- read.socket(datasocket)
```

Which resulted in:

> Error in read.socket(datasocket) : 
>     embedded nul in string: 'X\n\0\0\0\002\0\003\004\002\0\002\003\0'

The function read.socket() tries to read a string and doesn't accept null bytes.

Is there a way to read socket data to a raw vector in R?

Comment: I have found the solution by using readBin(), when I have completed my code I will post it over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R server-side:

```
library(sys)    

COMMAND = "python"
PATH_TO_SCRIPT='/lengthCheck.py'
allArgs = c(PATH_TO_SCRIPT)
sys::exec_background(COMMAND, args = allArgs, std_out = TRUE, std_err = TRUE)    

datasocket <- socketConnection(port = 1205, server = TRUE, open = "w+b", blocking = TRUE)
on.exit(close(datasocket))
datasize <- readBin(datasocket, what = "double")
data <- readBin(datasocket, what = "raw", n = datasize)
```

Python client-side:

```
import struct
import socket
import time    

your_raw_array_to_send = bytearray([0x58, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00])
arrayLength = len(your_raw_array_to_send)    

datasize = struct.pack('d', arrayLength)    

# Wait 100ms for R to set up a listening socket
time.sleep(.100)    

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('localhost', 1205))
client_socket.send(datasize)    

client_socket.send(your_raw_array_to_send)
client_socket.close()
```